# Samsung Ativ S - Any major known issues?

Tags: samsung-ativ-s

I am considering purchasing a new phone. After a little searching, the [Samsung Ativ S](http://www.samsung.com/ca/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/smartphones/SGH-T899ALMBMC) model seemed to fit many of my personal criteria. But after trying to find this phone in stores or used ones being sold by individuals ( in my country ), I stumbled upon an interesting observation.

The online stores I found that are listing this phone USED TO sell it, but have removed it from the list ( one of more popular ones did it in August 2013 ). Also, some of those stores sold this phone at a massive discount price before it was removed ( as high as 66% off ). Then I tried to find a used phone from the online market. There I have found 4 people selling it, and all of them are selling it from 3 - 6 months after purchase.

My question is, are there any major known issues with it? Should I be cautious before purchasing it ?

Comment: No more suspicious than not being able to find Philips TVs in store, etc. - it may just be a case that the carriers in your area get a better profit margin on Samsung Android devices, so they've cleared their stock of Aitv - that doesn't mean there's anything wrong or inferior with it though. Better to read reviews, either customer or journalist (who of course, may have an agenda of their own)

Comment: @RowlandShaw - thank you for your comment, another good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your question may be opinion based and off topic, I will answer it anyway.

> The online stores I found that are listing this phone USED TO sell it, but have removed it from the list ( one of more popular ones did it in August 2013 ).

I am not sure which country stores you are referring to but I am in Canada and the phone is available on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14/177-6311342-2709315?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=samsung%20ativ%20s&sprefix=samsung%20ativ%20s,aps,242&rh=i%3aaps,k%3asamsung%20ativ%20s) as well as [phone carriers](http://www.rogers.com/business/on/en/smallbusiness/products/wireless/devices/details?sku=ATIVSGRY).

> Also, some of those stores sold this phone at a massive discount price before it was removed ( as high as 66% off ).

This has been common with several Windows Phone devices. In fact, the best ever selling Windows Phone, the [Lumia 520](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-device-stats-february-2014) has been consistently on "sale" for as low as $99 in the States. Apart from the fact that it may be a ploy to increase market share, the phone was also agreed to be one of the best "value for money" phones. So when it comes to Windows Phone, low prices does not always mean low quality.

> Then I tried to find a used phone from the online market. There I have found 4 people selling it, and all of them are selling it from 3 - 6 months after purchase.

It could easily be argued that the more popular a device is, the more of it you will find being circulated online. Search for any Android device on Amazon- you will see plenty of these being sold second hand. It has nothing to do with the quality of the device.

**In summary, I wouldn't say that there is anything unusual about what you've noticed. [A good way to gauge the quality of a product is to check out what other people say about it on sites like Amazon. At this time, the phone is rated 4/5.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B090QRM)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was aware that this question might seem opinion based, but after another look it reveals that it asks for knowledge based on user experience. About the stores tale: I live in a small country and there aren't that many stores and huge selection of models. But the funny thing was, that those few stores that sold the Ativ S model, did it for a short time, and then all cancelled it. Some with huge discount. These facts just had to raise some suspicion on my side, and the result is the question I have posted here. Thank you again.